# jQuery: Cannot change style of element after selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code. Where you see "alert([...]);", an alert pops up. Why doesn't the CSS style change? The 'click' event **doesn't** fire either!

```
resolveSideMenuAddress: function () {
    var firstLink = $("#masterHeaderMenu .masterHeaderMenuButton a:first");

    function select(link) {
        alert('i alert');
        link.css({
            'color': '#9a4d9e',
            'cursor': 'default'
        });
        alert('color and cursor not changed');
        link.click(function () {
            alert('click');
            return false;
        });
    }

    if (window.location.pathname === firstLink.attr('href')) {
        alert('i alert');
        select(firstLink);
    }
}
```

I've tried addClass() and can't change the color of the link that way either.

Comment: You should accept some answers to other questions to encourage people to put the effort into responding.

Comment: you have the same alert twice - are you seeing it pop up twice?

Comment: Yes I am. Excellent question. I'm sorry for being a jQuery newb.

Comment: you should post the basics of the dom structure (like some sample html) for the elements. Also, does the following alert show? "alert('color and cursor not changed');"

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not actually firing the click event, but rather applying a click handler to the link.  It won't fire until you actually click the link.  If you want existing click handlers to be run you can try `link.click()` (without the function).  If you want the link to actually be taken, you should simply set the location to the value of the link's href attribute.  Second, I'm not sure why the CSS isn't being applied properly.  It looks ok to me.  I'd suggest using Firefox/Firebug and inspecting the element after the function has run to see what styles are actually in use.

Comment: I think he is aware of this, and says the problem is that the event is not triggered even when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try using $(link) instead of just link
like this:

```
resolveSideMenuAddress: function () {
    var firstLink = $("#masterHeaderMenu .masterHeaderMenuButton a:first");

    function select(link) {
        alert('i alert');
        $(link).css({
            'color': '#9a4d9e',
            'cursor': 'default'
        });
        alert('color and cursor not changed');
        $(link).click(function () {
            alert('click');
            return false;
        });
    }

    if (window.location.pathname === firstLink.attr('href')) {
        alert('i alert');
        select(firstLink);
    }
}
```